# Memory address of list name and list elements

Tags: python, list, memory-management, cpython

I know that list elements are objects in heap and those objects have their references in stack.

```
**x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(id(x[0]))             -> 01014518
print(id(x[1]))             -> 01014528
print(id(x[2]))             -> 01014556

print(id(x))                -> 18458914**
```

where the memory address of list name is? And the relationship of list name address with the elements' address?

Comment: Python has no concept of memory addresses. The use of a pointer to *construct*  an id value is an implementation detail of CPython.

Comment: As far as you know, the heap could be a SQL database, not stored in memory at all.

Comment: "those objects have their references in stack" is also incorrect.

Comment: Do accept and upvote the answer if you think it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

For the implementation of a list a contiguous array of references to other objects is used. Python keeps a pointer to this array and the array’s length is stored in a list head structure. When items are appended or inserted the array of references is resized.

This simply means that x points to an address where an array of addresses is present and each element of that array points to another address where anther object(int,float,list) is present. And that is reason why addresses of each element in that list point to another object which might be list, int, string .....

Refer to this link has a better explanation [memory allocation](https://towardsdatascience.com/memory-management-in-python-6bea0c8aecc9#:%7E:text=The%20Python%20memory%20manager%20manages%20chunks%20of%20memory%20called%20%E2%80%9CBlocks,object%20of%20the%20same%20size.)